# Excel IFERROR evaluates #VALUE and returns number

Tags: excel-formula

[Screenshot showing #VALUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQozo.jpg)
[Screenshot of Answer from'Evaluate Formula' Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydnYE.jpg)

My equation in the cell returns a number when it should be blank. When evaluating the formula, it seems it should be blank since the IFERROR function evaluates #VALUE but still returns a number. Here is the original formula:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($F$64:$F$1000,SMALL(IF(AND($G64:G64=$R$2,$A$64:A64>=($A$64-6)),ROW($F$64:$F$1000)-MIN(ROW($F$64:$F$1000))+1),ROWS($J$15:J15))),"")}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What may be happening is that `SMALL` is returning `0`. If that is so, then `INDEX($F$64:$F$1000,0)` will return the entire array `$F$64:$F$1000`. Since that's not an error, `IFERROR` does not respond to an error but instead returns `$F$64:$F$1000`.

Side note:
`AND` returns a single True/False value rather than an array of values so if often does not work as expected in array (`CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER`) formulas. Depending on the behavior your designing you may need to replace the `AND` with nested `IF` functions.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes I agree upon looking at the data closer this seems to be what's happening. Thank you very much for your help!